# FCM Notification color attribute is not working

Tags: android, firebase, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Using the following payload syntax I am trying to achieve a coloured notification:

```
const payload = {
  notification : {
    title : "App title",
    body : "You have new messages",
    icon : "not_icon_white2",
    color : "#2a6d57",
    sound : "default",
    click_action : "do something"
  }
};
```

The icon in the status bar is displayed correctly (as white) yet in the notification drawer my notification behaves like this:
[image]

The title color is correct, yet the notification icon remains white, resulting in a poor visual experience.

I am using (as you can see above) the `color` attribute in the payload that should change the color of the icon as well.

Official docs:

> color
>   Optional, string
>   The notification's icon color, expressed in #rrggbb format.

**Why is the notification icon color not changing to the color I specified in the payload?**

Could the icon drawable (a white one with transparent portions) be the cause here?

NOTE: This question regards FCM **notification payload** and **NOT** data. Also, the question regards the background case of sending the content, not foreground.

Comment: heyv , ive used exactly your color and the color changed of notification dot

Answer (score 0):

you should use capital char as this
in your code
 `'color':'#2A6D57'`
[image]